# Select2 resizing box during load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I've been struggling massively to understand this issue and how to fix it.

Essentially, using a standard select2() box, when loading the page, the selection box starts at a slightly larger sized box with a small font and then resizes itself to a smaller sized box.

I am experiencing this issue, and if you look at https://select2.github.io/examples.html

You will see this happens on several of the examples (at least using Chrome)

I cannot reasonably reproduce this error and am using a super standard

```
$('#myselect').select2();
```

Is there anyone who can give me some sort of idea why and when this resizing would occur?

EDIT:

I've discovered that the issue has to do with the fact that it starts with Bootstrap styling, and then select2 adds classes to it, thereby changing the formatting of the output.

For whatever reason, I've struggled to exactly emulate the css properties of select.form-control without select2 as looking the same as with select2, despite painstakingly looking over the computed css properties.

I would very much so prefer to have the solution above - where the select before and after select2 adds classes is visually identical.

For now however, I have created a makeshift solution which is

In css:

```
#myselect
{
    display:none;
}
```

Once select2 loads the select completely, it will become visible.

The issue with this solution is that the bar will temporarily not show up immediately upon loading the page, and so it will look like it "pops up" on your page.

Comment: Try to comment each css and check for testing purpose.

Comment: You can change the css for class `.select2-container .select2-selection--single` having `height:28px`

Comment: I am not a pro but why don't you add  `opacity:0;` to select it looks fine https://jsfiddle.net/j2nbv0Ld/

Comment: also you can add 32px height to select something like https://jsfiddle.net/j2nbv0Ld/3/

Comment: page loading is not really important , use `class` instead of `id` to hide your `select`s